# Error: Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

The compiler gives me an error: "Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'. The offending line is:

```
change[j]=oper[integer(A[i][j]+A[i][j+1])][0];
```

Where is my trouble?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string mas[10000000],oper[100];

int integer(string a)
{
    int numb;
    istringstream(a)>>numb;
    return numb;
}

int main()
{
    int l,k,i,d=0;
    string temp1,temp2,s,t,ans="-1",change;
    vector<string> A,B;
    for (i=0;i<10000000;++i)
    mas[i]="-1";
    for (i=0;i<100;++i)
        oper[i]="-1";
    cin>>l>>s>>t>>k;
    for (i=0;i<k;++i)
    {
        cin>>temp1>>temp2;
        oper[integer(temp1)]=temp2;
    }
    A.push_back(s);
    while(A.size()>0)
    {
        if (ans!="-1")
            break;
        for (i=0;i<A.size();++i)
        {
            if (ans!="-1")
                break;
            for (int j=0;j<l-1;++j)
            {
                change=A[i];
                change[j]=oper[integer(A[i][j]+A[i][j+1])][0];
                change[j+1]=oper[integer(A[i][j]+A[i][j+1])][1];
                if(oper[integer(A[i][j]+A[i][j+1])]!="-1" && mas[integer(change)]!="-1")
            {
                if (mas[integer(change)]==t)
                {
                    ans=d;
                    break;
                }
                mas[integer(change)]=d+1;
                B.push_back(change);
            }
        }
    }
    A=B;
    B.clear();
    }
    cout<<ans<<endl;;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Adding two characters gives an integer. `integer` takes a string.

Comment: My god, it's full of brackets!

Comment: @dyp's comment refers to the original title; it's been modified since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`integer` converts a `string` to `int`. But you are passing in a `char`, not a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

A is vector<std::string>, so A[j] is string, so A[j][i] is character of the string.

Without trying to understand what is the purpose, I can say that A[j][i] + A[j][i+1] sums the character **values**, so if both characters are 'A' and as 'A' is represented by 65, the result value would be 130 ->'é'

Then you take this char and put it in method, that accepts string, so the char is not valid input.